# How to have a `TextField`'s label that wraps if too long?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, flutter-textinputfield

I'm trying to have a long `TextField`'s label that doesn't overflow but wraps.

If I use `InputDecoration({String labelText})`, the label overflows:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Very veryy veryyy veryyyy veryyyyy long loong looong loooong lable text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text',
  ),
),
```

[image]

I tried to use `InputDecoration({Widget label})` instead with a `Text` that would wrap, but the layout has issues: the label is over the inputted value:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: Text('Very veryy veryyy veryyyy veryyyyy long loong looong loooong lable text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text'),
  ),
),
```

[image]

How can I properly wrap a long label in a `TextField`?

Answer (score 0):

try with `Expanded` widget as below:

```
    Row(
                        children: const [
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
                              label: Text(
                                  'Very veryy veryyy veryyyy veryyyyy long loong looong loooong lable text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text'),
                            ),
                          ))
                        ],
                      ),
```

Comment: I tried your code, the `Row` + `Expanded` doesn't change anything. The `contentPadding` only fixes the issue when the label is 2 lines long but not if it is longer. I'm don't think that is a proper approach for a responsive design solution